# How can I optimize my sql query for lower execution time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to search the companies containing the name 'CCR Tech', I have 30 tables containing the same column name, the execution time of my sql query is around 6 sec which is too high. How can I optimize my sql query?

My query:

```
 SELECT c.corporate_identification_number as cin, c.company_name as label FROM 
(SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_west_bengal WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_uttrkhand WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_uttar_pradesh WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_ut WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%'
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_telengana WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_tamil_nadu WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_rajasthan WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_punjab WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_odisha WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_nagaland WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_mizoram WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_meghalaya WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_manipur WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_maharastra WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_madhya_pradesh WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_kerala WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_karnataka WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_jharkhand WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_jammu_kashmir WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_haryana WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_gujarat WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_goa WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_delhi WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_bihar WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_assam WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_arunachal_pradesh WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM jas_company_master_andhra_pradesh WHERE LOWER(company_name) LIKE 'ccr tech%') as c 
WHERE 1
```

Comment: That is a very poor design. You should fix your design to be something like: `jas_company_master (id..., other columns, master_table_type_id fk_to_master_table_type); master_table_type(id, name) this one should have those 30 different types` that way your query would be in just one table. and with proper index on that field.

Comment: On a side note, you have jas_company_master_ut several times.

Comment: Try using LEFT JOINs between tables Instead of Union. (if you cannot change the schema)

Comment: For what you have, depending on your mysql configuration you can start by removing the `lower` function

Comment: And left only one jas_company_master_ut as @Mike suggested.

Comment: Make sure those tables have indexes on company_name. If you don't have indexes, adding them will speed things up considerably, even with the messy design you have right now.

Comment: do you have indexes on these tables? if not, consider adding one on company_name.
And change the schema...

Comment: Please, follow @JorgeCampos advice on reviewing the design, and remove the multiple jas_company_master_ut references. On the pure "optimize this query" I would avoid all the `select *` (use `select corporate_identification_number, company_name`) and consider using UNION ALL instead of UNION (I'm assuming the different tables shouldn't contain the same corporate_identification_number).

Comment: My 30 tables has same schema but data are not same each table contains unique identification number. Maximum table contains more than 50 thousands row. Please explain in detail on answer box .. @Jorge Campos

Comment: What is your end goal? Is it to get all the **Columns for all 30 tables** where the company name = 'ccr tech%'?

Comment: Do you have one table for different geographies? Is there really a companies table for each region, rather than a "region" column in the companies table?

Comment: Boss every table have region column but how your comment is related to this topic? @NevilleK

Comment: I set index on comany_name and using UNION ALL instead of UNION and select only 2 columns instead of * but execution time still showing 6.0439 seconds. So next what is the solution??

Comment: 50000 rows is nothing. It's tiny. All of these `jas_company_master` should be 1 table. 1 table. That's it. In that new 1 table add all the same columns, plus a new one called "Region" or whatever in which you store which region the record is for. Then instead of a union, you just select from that 1 table. You will get no better optimization using your not so great schema.

Comment: If I merge all tables in to one it may be more than 50 lacks data in one table. I don't know it is feasible solution or not!!